# Running Pyad in flask

Tags: python, flask

I am attempting to run pyad in a flask app.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, request
from wtforms import Form, TextField, TextAreaField, validators, StringField, SubmitField
from pyad import *
import folder_module

# App config.
DEBUG = True
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'SECRETKEY'

class ReusableForm(Form):
    uid1 = TextField('UID1:', validators=[validators.required()])
    uid2 = TextField('UID2:', validators=[validators.required()])
    folder = TextField('Folder Name:', validators=[validators.required()])

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def fold():
    form = ReusableForm(request.form)

    print(form.errors)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        uid1 = request.form['uid1']
        uid2 = request.form['uid2']
        foldername = request.form['folder']
        if form.validate():
            ou = pyad.adcontainer.ADContainer.from_dn("ou=Groups, dc=ad, dc=test, dc=com")
            flash(ou)

        else:
            flash('All the form fields are required. ')

    return render_template('folder.html', form=form)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I am hoping that I can call into pyad to create a security group. But even running a query on the ad container (ou via dn in this case) gives me a win32 error. The main fail error is resulted from that line and gives the following win32types error.

```
    pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147221020), None)
```

I have tried running this in 32bit and 64 bit python, as well as with AD.setdefault auth.

Is there anything else I can do?

[pywintypes.com error when running pyad.adgroup on flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109346/pywintypes-com-error-when-running-pyad-adgroup-on-flask)
It looks like someone else has a similar question

Answer (score 1):

I solve this error using pythoncom library inside any route.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import pythoncom
import pyad

@app.route('/')
def index():
    pythoncom.CoInitialize()
```

Comment: Thanks this did the trick for me. No need for route annotation though, a simple call to pythoncom.CoInitialize() seems sufficient

Comment: If you use pyad a lot, a hook can be used instead: 
`>@app.before_request`, 
`>def hook():`, 
`>    pythoncom.CoInitialize()`